# Errors with rxjs v6 and rxjs/operators

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am having trouble implementing rxjs v6 and rxjs/operators:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { startWith, debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

    public products$: Observable<Product[]>;
    public searchTerm: string = '';

    private searchSubject: Subject<string> = new Subject();
    private reloadProductsList: Subject<void> = new Subject();

    constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

    ng OnInit() {
        this.products$ = this.searchSubject
            .pipe(startWith(this.searchTerm), debounceTime(300));
    }
    ...
}
```

The specific error is with `this.products$` in `ngOnInit()`.  Here is the error:

```
Type 'Observable<string | Product[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Product[]>'.
Type 'string | Product[]' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'
```

The error is confusing to me.  Can you assist?

Comment: Hmm, neither of these suggestions worked.  Would you be willing to supply a coding example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the issue is with `startWith(this.searchTerm)`. You can't start with that since it is a string and `this.products$` is `Observable<Product[]>;`. Also, `this.searchSubject` is `Subject<string>`.

Are you sure it's not `this.products$ = this.productService.getProducts();`, something like this?

Comment: OK, good.  I'm getting closer.  The call to:   this.products$ = this.productService.getProducts( "" );  results in:    status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/api/product".  So, is there a way to somehow query the localhost to see why it is not finding my api call?  Thank you.

Comment: constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getProducts(query: string): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>('/api/product');
  }

Comment: I am not sure, but you can't assign an observable of string to observable of product array